# algorithm2e - Caption without text

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

In the following code I would like to have a caption without text. In the following MWE there are unwanted colons because the caption is **Algorithm 1:** .

How can I fix that ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{}

    \While{\dots}{
        \dots
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the relevant options:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{}% no separator, default colon
\SetAlCapNameSty{}% no caption text

 \While{\dots}{
   \dots
 }

\caption{}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If *all* your algorithms have no text in captions, you can place the two commands in the preamble:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{}% no separator, default colon
\SetAlCapNameSty{}% no caption text

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

 \While{\dots}{
   \dots
 }

\caption{This text won't appear}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If only some of the captions should be void, you can do

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\newcommand{\voidcaption}[2][]{%
  \SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{}% no separator, default colon
  \SetAlCapNameSty{}% no caption text
  \caption{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

 \While{\dots}{
   \dots
 }

\voidcaption{This text won't appear}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I'd not define `\voidcaption` without arguments, so that it would be easy to go back and typeset the given text instead.

Comment: Thanks. Can I update your answer by adding a special macro `\algojustcaption` that does all the job ?

Comment: @projetmbc I added some suggestions.

Comment: I don't do the same thing. I prefer to build a macro using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, sucha as to localize the change of the settings, and calling `\caption` inside this group.

Comment: @projetmbc Why? The `algorithm` environment already provides for grouping.

Comment: You're right. I have done a weird test that makes me use an useful group. Your macro does not product any caption : there is a missing \caption{} in your void macro.

Comment: @projetmbc Added, thanks.